# Increase vertical space for a mark in Lilypond

Tags: lilypond

Practically, looking for an appropriate override to move the \mark a bit off the system.

[image]

There is enough space around and I would like to use it, so that the content is not too cramped together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you want something like this?

```
\new DrumStaff {
  s1*4
  \section
  \once\override Score.RehearsalMark.self-alignment-X = #LEFT
  \once\override Score.RehearsalMark.padding = #3
  \mark \markup\box "Bridge"
  s1*4
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's right. The title of the question is about _vertical_ space; `self-alignment-X` changes horizontal alignment. I would think `Y-offset` should be used.

Comment: @Neal Ah, yeah. I misunderstood this from the way it was drawn, I’ve edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you! I should probably make the RehearsalMark.padding override a default for my sheets.